# Entity Framework e construtor parametrizado

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, parâmetros, construtor

Quando eu crio domínios, eu geralmente crio um construtor parametrizado para o mesmo:

```
namespace Models
{
    public class Unity
    {
        public string Abreviation { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Unity (string abreviation, string description)
        {
            Abreviation = abreviation;
            Description = description;
        }

        public Unity ( ) { }
    }
}
```

Dessa forma o usuário da classe tem a opção de passar o valor das propriedades no mesmo momento da instanciação do objeto.
Ou passa-los posteriormente através dos setters.

Isso é válido no EF?

Comment: Não creio que há necessidade, sendo que você pode fazer `var unity = new Unity{Abreviation = "un", Description = "unity"};`. Mas como assim se é válido no EF? Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: É válido sim ... !!! Isso vai de cada desenvolvedor, ou grupo de desenvolvimento, ou regra seguida. Mas isso não tem problema

Comment: Eu diria que é algo inútil. Posso fazer assim: `var unity = new Unity { Abbreviation = abbreviation, Description = description };`

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez porque inutil, existe desenvolvimento com DDD que isso é mais do que válido ... porque inutil ?

Comment: Isto pode te ajudar ou talvez responder:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101 O EF não tem uma necessidade específica quanto a isto. O segundo construtor vazio faz com que o primeiro seja desnecessário, conforme já informou o Randrade. Se só existisse o primeiro seria diferent.

Comment: @João DDD. Tá explicado.

Comment: @Randrade Quero dizer, se eu passar os valores das propriedades através do construtor, dar um Add e mandar salvar? O EF salvará normalmente?
Não lembrava dessa sintaxe do C#, como vim de outras linguagens que não tem o mesmo recurso, acabo trazendo junto alguns hábitos.

Comment: Não me aprofundei mais pois é um assunto que já possui respostas no site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Se eu passar os valores das propriedades através do construtor, dar um Add e mandar salvar? O EF salvará normalmente?

Sim, ele salvará normalmente.

Ao criar um construtor com parâmetros, ao instanciar passando os parâmetros você estará criando um objeto normalmente. Não é normal fazer isso em `C#`, mas funciona.

[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/20615) poderá lhe ajudar a entender um pouco mais.

Leia também [este comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73530/para-que-serve-um-construtor#comment150730_73531), acho que ajudará a entender um pouco mais.

Elaborei [este exemplo simples para você ver funcionando o que foi dito.](https://github.com/renilsonmeneguci/SaveWithConstructorParameters)

Comment: Desculpe retomar essa pergunta, mas surgiu uma outra dúvida relacionada ao assunto.
Suponha em um domínio eu crie um construtor parametrizado para garantir que algumas propriedades da classe sejam inicializadas.
O EF tem a inteligência de perceber o construtor com parâmetros e usá-lo na hora de criar os objetos?
Ou seja, o EF deve instanciar o objeto passando os parâmetros para o construtor `var anyObject = new AnyObject(par1, par2, ...)` e não mais pelo construtor padrão vazio.
EF tem essa inteligência de perceber que existe um construtor com parâmetros?
Não sei se fui claro na pergunta.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Acho que está tendo uma confusão sobre o que é o Entity Framework e o que é `C#`. Isso que você está falando é `C#`, o EF entra apenas quando for realizar alguma operação no banco (no seu caso). Se o objeto estiver com os valores, o EF irá salvar aqueles valores.

Comment: Mas quando eu faço uma consulta por exemplo, o EF não me devolve os resultados na forma de domínios. Por exemplo, se eu pedir o cliente cujo ID é 250, de que forma ele me devolve isso? Não seria na forma de um objeto Client com os valores definido nas propriedades e no caso de mais de um resultado devolveria uma coleção de Clients?
Por exemplo:
`var pedidos = from p in contexto.Orders select p;`
 `pedidos.ToList();`

O que retorna o método `ToList()` ?

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Abra outra pergunta sobre o assunto, você está fazendo uma enorme confusão. Parâmetros ao instanciar um objeto é uma coisa, o retorno do **EF** é outra. Um é do `C#` e o outro é do **EF**, respectivamente. Outra, o método `ToList()` irá lhe retornar uma lista, caso queira somente um objeto, use o `First()` ou o `FirstOrDefault()`, dependendo do caso.

Answer (score -1):

O primeiro construtor é válido e recomendado no caso de estares usando DDD e quiser aplicar o TDD, porém neste caso o segundo construtor deveria ser privado, apenas para que pudesse ser utilizado na EF Migrations.
Ref: [http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/entity-framework-private-constructors-and-private-setters](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/entity-framework-private-constructors-and-private-setters/)

Comment: Isto está incorreto. O procedimento de *Seed* não demanda construtores privados.